# Attempting to register an unknown factory: `controller:application`

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit

Here's a simplified version of my `PuzzleController`:

```
// app/controllers/puzzle.js
export default Em.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application']
});
```

And here's my controller test:

```
// tests/unit/controllers/puzzle-test.js
import { 
    moduleFor,
    test
} from 'ember-qunit';

moduleFor('controller:puzzle', 'PuzzleController', { 
    needs: ['controller:application']
});

test('it exists', function() { 
    var controller = this.subject();
    ok(controller);
});
```

I get this error when running `ember test`:

```
Attempting to register an unknown factory: `controller:application`
```

I'm using Ember 1.7.0, ember-cli 0.1.1. It seems like Ember should definitely recognize the `controller:application` selector. Am I using the wrong syntax here?

Comment: What does your application controller looks like?  And ember-qunit isn't ember, it's a third party tool created by instructure to help testing.  It's the thing that is looking for the controller you specified, and failing to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you'll need to create the application controller.

Run `ember g controller application` and then try again.

I don't think ember-testing will work with an automagically generated controller. You need to define it.